# Trying to find the best norm on $c_{00}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, functional-analysis, normed-spaces

We know that the definition of $c$, $c_{0}$ and $c_{00}$ for $K= \mathbb{C}$ and $x=(x(1), x(2), ...)$, is as follows
$$c= \{ x \in l^{ \infty}: x(j) \ \  \mbox{converges in K as}\ \  j \to \infty \},$$
$$c_{0}= \{ x \in c: x(j) \to 0  \mbox{ as}\ \  j \to \infty \},$$
$$c_{00}= \{ x \in l^{p}: \mbox{ all but finitely many } x(j) \mbox{'s are equal to 0}\}.$$

$c_{00}$ is a dense vector subspace of $l^{p} , 1 \le p < \infty$ . If $X=l^{\infty}$  and    $\ Y=c_{00 }$  then $Y$ is a subspace of $X$, but $Y$ is not closed in $X$. In fact $x_{n}= (1, ..., \frac{1}{n}, 0, 0, ...) \in c_{00} $ for each $n=1,2, ..., $ but $x_{n} \to (1, \frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{3} ,... ) \notin c_{00}$.with this example we can claim that the closure $c_{00}$ is $c_{0}$( and this claim is true!). According to the example $c_{00}$ is not complete and so there is no Dedicated norm for $c_{00}$. On the other hand $c_{0}$ is a subspace of $l^{ \infty}$ and its norm is $\lVert x \rVert_{ \infty}= \sup \big\{ |x(j)| , j=1,2,...\big \}$, $c_{00}$ is a subspace of $l^{p}$ and its norm is $\lVert x \rVert_{p}=( |x(1)|^{p}+|x(2)|^{p}+...)^{ \frac{1}{p}}$ . Is it possible to use $ \lVert \cdot \rVert_{\infty}$ for $c_{00}$? Which is better for $c_{00}$? $\lVert x \rVert_{p}$ or $\lVert x \rVert_{ \infty}$?

Comment: Why negative score?

Answer (score 1):

$c_{00}$ has no preferred norm because it's a subspace of $\ell_p$ for all $1 \le p \le \infty$. This is an advantage: when proving things about sequence spaces, we can often make use of the fact that $c_{00}$ is contained in any of these spaces; in other words, we can safely apply any $\| \cdot \|_p$ norm (even $p = \infty$) for sequences in $c_{00}$. None of these norms is "better" for $c_{00}$; the point is that it could be advantageous to use different norms depending on the situation.

The other spaces you mentioned are different: $c$ and $c_0$ are subspaces of $\ell_\infty$ but *not* of any other $\ell_p$. To give one example, the sequence you mentioned $x = (1, \frac 1 2, \frac 1 3, \frac 1 4, \cdots)$ is in $c_0$ and $\ell_\infty$ but it's not in $\ell_1$ because the harmonic series diverges. In general, the sequence $x_n = n^{-1/p}$ is in $c_0$ but not in $\ell_p$.

Answer (score 1):

You may know that
$$
p \leq q \Longrightarrow \lvert \lvert \cdot \rvert \rvert_{\ell^q} \leq \lvert \lvert \cdot \rvert \rvert_{\ell^p}
$$
so that among the $\ell^p$ norms the one which controlls the most what is happening in $c_{00}$ is the $\ell^1$-norm. But as you said, the normed space $(c_{00}, \lvert \lvert \cdot \rvert \rvert _{\ell^1})$ is not complete. In fact the Baire category theorem tells you that since this vector space has countable algebraic dimension, no norm can make it complete. So there is no hope to endow this set of a good norm.

If you really want to put a good topology on this space, maybe it can be interesting to endow it of something looking like the topology on $C_c^\infty$. Namely a sequence $(x_j)$ of $c_{00}$ converges to $0$ if and only if the supports are uniformly boundeds and the convergence is uniform the convergence happens in $\lvert \lvert \cdot \rvert \rvert _{\ell^1}$:
$$
\exists N \in \mathbb N,\quad \forall j \in \mathbb N,\quad \forall n  \geq N,\quad x_j(n) = 0
$$
and
$$
\lvert \lvert x_j \rvert \rvert _{\ell^1} \longrightarrow 0.
$$
Note that by linearity this defines a convergence notion on the whole space. Note also that because the norms on $\mathbb R^n$ are all equivalent the last norm can be replaced by any $\ell^p$ norm. If you are interested this construction gives rise to $\mathbb R^\infty$ which is an inductive limit of Banach spaces and enjoys several nice property "of a space of good test functions where the topology is very tight".